# Brocade/Ruckus per vlan spanning tree vs Cisco

Tags: cisco, brocade, ieee-802.1w

Brocade = `(config-vlan-10)#spanning-tree rstp`
This seems to enable rstp per vlan.  This example enabling it on vlan 10.

Cisco = `spanning-tree mode rapid-pvst`
This enables Rapid PVST+ under the covers from my understanding.

My question is, would the brocade configuration as is, allow it to inter-operate with a Cisco SW on vlan 10 PVST+?

i.e.  the Brocade would participate in the Cisco SW per vlan rapid spanning tree.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

RSTP is an IEEE STP that works on the port level only and is unaware of VLANs. For VLANs to form different spanning trees you require *M*STP and an appropriate configuration using multiple instances (MSTI). Each of these instances forms its own spanning tree and you use those instances to group your VLANs and distribute their over your redundant links.

Cisco's proprietary RPVST+ is not compatible with either classic (obsolete) STP, RSTP or MSTP. You'll need to choose which protocol to use. Many other vendors support RPVST but not all do. Check the Ruckus manual.

Generally, RPVST+ is much easier to implement but MSTP allows you total control over how your spanning trees are formed.